# Python POST ordered params

Tags: python, http

I have a web service that accepts passed in params using http POST but in a specific order, eg (name,password,data).  I have tried to use httplib but all the Python http POST libraries seem to take a dictionary, which is an unordered data structure.  Any thoughts on how to http POST params in order for Python?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is order important?  Form fields are labeled.  Did you make a mistake and give them all have the same label?

Comment: Yes, it turned out order didn't matter.  I had an incorrect param value that was causing it to fail and send back an error message.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you need a specific order in the POST parameters in the first place? As far as I know there are no requirements that POST parameter order is preserved by web servers.

Every language I have used, has used a dictionary type object to hold these parameters as they are inherently key/value pairs.